# Gitlab produces 500 error after committing several new files

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab

After adding several new files to my project, upon submitting a merge request Git presents an error with the following text;

"500. We're sorry but something went wrong. Please contact your GitLab administrator if this problem persists."

I have tested with a separate commit which worked fine suggesting that it is the content that I am pushing onto Git that is serving the error.

I have checked online such as the following threads -

https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/7183

https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/1774

Neither of which provide the solution.

The content I am adding includes some fonts, JS, css and an images folder - all of which work fine outside of Git.

I'm wondering if Git can pick up file names and produce errors if there are conflicts. Does anyone know if this is possible? Or any other ideas as to what the problem could be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "... and an images folder" How big is that images folder? Perhaps Gitlab is refusing commits/pushes that are too large...

Comment: That's a good point, it's only several mb mind, but I will look into this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

500 Internal Server errors could be many things. Do the log files (e.g. `/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log`) show anything relating to the 500 error?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue. Mine specifically was around creating a new repository on my newly updated Gitlab instance (I am now running 8.2.1). Clearing the cache seemed to work.

```
sudo gitlab-rake cache:clear
```